# Meteor Collection fetch working after insert only

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, mongo-collection

I am fetching data from Mongo Database using Collections but it not returning any data while fetching but when i insert data it then returns fetch call .

```
Template.message.events({
    'click #tag_message-actions__button' : function(){
            const { msg } = this;
            console.log("msgg",this);
            TaggedMessages.insert({
            message:msg.msg,
            messageId : msg._id,
            taggedAt: new Date(),
        }); 

    }
});
```

This for fetching

```
const nnn = TaggedMessages.find().forEach((item) => { 
    console.log("teggitem",item)
});
// const nnn =TaggedMessages.find({},{messageId :  msg._id})
console.log("tegg",TaggedMessages.find())
```

Here i am allowing to to insert using Meteor.allow in server side

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

var TaggedMessages = new Mongo.Collection('rocketchat_taggedmessages');
TaggedMessages.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
         return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
         return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
         return true;
  },

});
```

Comment: Note: allow/deny is highly discouraged due to a known security vulnerability. Now to your question: how do you publish/subcribe the data? Could you please add that to the code?

Comment: yes, i removed allow and used publish and subscribe way and it worked then

Comment: So it works now? If not, please add the publish/subscribe code.

Comment: it worked with publish subscribe